# In browser Mongo DB sidebar

Tags: mongodb, meteor

What's this 'in-browser' MongoDB sidebar Max Harris from Meteor is using in this video at timecode 11:16 ?

https://www.meteor.com/blog/2015/04/29/two-weeks-with-react-and-meteor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh yes, the insanely awesome mongol plug in!

https://github.com/msavin/Mongol

Comment: Thanks! It sure looks insanely awsome! :D

Comment: Please do feel free to accept the answer :) also if you haven't used the other awesome tool he used in there, make sure to check out Velocity test runner: https://github.com/meteor-velocity/velocity

Comment: haha :) I tried to accept it earlier, I'm not sure how to!  Oh.. duh.... got it. √

Cool, Velocity looks great!